# Get the base language string back from NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

We use `NSLocalizedString` throughout our app and localize for about 8 languages. `English` is the base language, and we have an instance where localized words are saved in the database. However, we have a tool that exports these, and we need to convert back to the base language (English) for those terms.

**Does `NSLocalizedString` provide a way to convert a localized string back to the base language?**

Comment: IF you need the base language string it is probably the key you include in the NSLocalizedString. Based on the key, look in the base language .strings file.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa does not provide that and, in general, it's not possible. It's quite possible that different strings in the base language were translated into identical strings in another language (either because they mean the same thing or because of homonyms). So, there could be no unique reverse localization.

Ideally, you should be using base language strings or an internal code everyplace other than presentation to the user. You should not store localized strings in a database.

For example, what if the app creates a database entry when one language is in effect, the user quits your app, changes the system language settings, and relaunches your app. Now the database has an entry that doesn't match either the base language term nor the current localization of that term. You would need not only a reverse localization of the current language but a reverse localization from all of the languages your app supports.